# In my case i want to put my export buttons in to dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to convert export data table buttons into a dropdown
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvvJ4.jpg)

simply like this dropdown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01ZQP.jpg)

please help me how can I put all these export buttons into dropdown.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this way the community can help you easily.

Answer (score 0):

it will cause some UX problem.
but if they are just a bunch of buttons, you can wrap then into a div and add a toggle button to show and hide.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).